# Serving static files from Jboss EAP 6.0

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, spring-mvc, jboss

In my project which contain multiple module, One module have images folder which we deploy in Jboss server. The problem with this approach is static content is moving every time here to there.

To solve this problem we thought to move images folder outside jboss  **(Jboss eap 6.0)** directory. But we have no idea how to map external files to jboss.

I got some similar  question but we have already mapped default (/) context to Root.war,
so how can I use a servlet to map all images from external files.

Please  suggest me better approach to solve this issue.

Comment: Why not keep all the images in the src/main/resources folder?

Comment: there is functionality upload image which may effect, I don't want to keep it with project. I want separate location on hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are outside the webapp directory, try using the usual `FileOutputStream` and `FileInputStream` classes to respectively write to and read from the disk.